# Still get data even there is a CORS issue in Nginx

Tags: nginx, cors

I'm trying to debug a CORS issue. Here's my configuration
I'm using http://www.test-cors.org/ to test my Nginx rules.
I get the message below in my browser's console when the method I use is OPTIONS. But I still received the data which is very weird

```
Failed to load http://www.example.com:8009/testcors: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.test-cors.org' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I get the message below if the method I use is GET. I also get the data

```
Failed to load http://www.example.com:8009/testcors: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.test-cors.org' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Here's my updated nginx configuration, 3rd update and I put it on a new file.

```
  ❯ cat /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx-mini.conf
  worker_processes  1;
  worker_rlimit_nofile 15000;

  error_log  logs/error.log;
  error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
  error_log  logs/error.log  info;

  events {
   worker_connections  5000;
   accept_mutex off;
  }


  http {
   include       mime.types;
   default_type  application/octet-stream;
   proxy_cookie_path / "/; HTTPOnly; Secure";

   types_hash_max_size 4096;
   access_log off;
   sendfile off;
   sendfile_max_chunk 512k;
   tcp_nopush      off;
   tcp_nodelay      on;
   output_buffers 1 3m;

   open_file_cache          max=10000 inactive=5m;
   open_file_cache_valid    2m;
   open_file_cache_min_uses 1;
   open_file_cache_errors   on;

   gzip on;
   gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
   gzip_http_version  1.1;
   gzip_comp_level    5;
   gzip_min_length    256;
   gzip_proxied       any;
   gzip_vary          on;

   gzip_types
     application/atom+xml
     application/javascript
     application/json
     application/rss+xml
     application/vnd.ms-fontobject
     application/x-font-ttf
     application/x-javascript
     application/x-web-app-manifest+json
     application/xhtml+xml
     application/xml
     application/xml+rss
     font/opentype
     image/svg+xml
     image/x-icon
     text/css
     text/javascript
     text/js
     text/plain
     text/x-component
     text/xml;

   # CORS
   map $http_origin $allow_origin {
     default "";
     ~example.com "$http_origin";
   }

   server {
     listen 8009;
     server_name www.example.com;
     access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
     error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

     location /testcors {
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $allow_origin;
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
           add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 60;
           add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
           add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
           return 204;
        }
        if ($request_method = 'POST') {
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $allow_origin;
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
           add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
        }

        if ($request_method = 'GET') {
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $allow_origin;
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
           add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
           add_header GETMETHOD accessed;
           add_header Content-Type "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }

       add_header Content-Type "application/json; charset=utf-8";
       return 200 '{"code": 200, "reason": "Testing CORS ..."}';
     }
   }
  }
```

I started it this way

```
sudo nginx -c /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx-mini.conf
```

ps ax | grep nginx shows the process

```
31528   ??  Ss     0:00.00 nginx: master process nginx -c /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx-mini.conf
31529   ??  S      0:00.00 nginx: worker process
31787 s003  R+     0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn nginx
```

netstat shows the tcp port associated with my nginx

```
❯ netstat -na|grep 8009
tcp4       0      0  *.8009                 *.*                    LISTEN
```

The ip address is correct

```
 ❯ ping www.example.com
 PING airborne.gogoinflight.com (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.042 ms
 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.067 ms
 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.132 ms
```

I made sure I'm connecting to my own locally running nginx server using curl

```
❯ curl http://www.example.com:8009/testcors
{"code": 200, "reason": "Testing CORS ..."}%
```

And the results are still the same(screenshots of chrome dev tools) https://i.stack.imgur.com/CB67D.jpg

Comment: The response in your images doesn't match the configuration you've posted. Check your nginx configuration with `nginx -t` and _restart_ nginx to ensure that it actually is running that configuration, and not an old configuration.

Comment: I did that. I did it again and also executed nginx -s reload. Here are the new screenshots, still got the data - https://imgur.com/a/tN1Bb

Comment: I updated my post. It's a complete nginx configuration plus some debugging commands. I am still not sure why I still get data. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not sending CORS headers in your `location /testcors`.

You only send these in the `server` block, for any other location.

The reason for this is that `add_header` directives in lower level blocks [completely override](https://nginx.org/r/add_header) those in higher level blocks. So, because you have used `add_header` in your `location`, you must also include all the other `add_header` directives again.

To keep your configuration DRY, you should consider [making an `include` file](https://nginx.org/r/include) which contains the common `add_header` directives, and then `include` it at each relevant point in the configuration.

Comment: Thanks for that, saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

WOOHOO!!! I finally got it to work!!! I learned that we have to tell nginx what we want to do if it doesn't match the origin. My first impression with Nginx is that it will automatically block domains if they are different. 99% of the examples I found doesn't say it.

```
# CORS
map $http_origin $allow_origin {
  default "blocked";
  ~example.com "allowed";
}

map $allow_origin $origin_is_allowed {
  allowed $http_origin;
}

location ~ /getapi/?(?<capture>.*) {
   if ($allow_origin = 'allowed') {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$origin_is_allowed";
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
      add_header Content-Type "application/json; charset=utf-8";
      proxy_pass http://localhost:7777/api/$capture;
   }
   if ($allow_origin = 'blocked') {
      add_header Content-Type "text/plain";
      return 403 "Your domain is not allowed!";
   }
}
```

Here is test-cors.org failing :) https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kKXY.png
Earlier it was able to get data even if there were cors errors